# Blackness in Radeon ProRender

Tags: rendering, materials, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I'm trying to use Radeon ProRender and it's materials library, however I meet a problem: some parts of objects with default materials (Bronze Brushed and Fabric Matte Solid Beige) look black:

[image: blackness]

How can I fix these black parts?

Comment: @RayMairlot please don't remove the tag, I added it intentionally because [it is relatively popular topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=prorender), and I also proposed fine description to it.

Comment: Hi. I removed it for a reason. Using [this search](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=radeon%20prorender%20is%3aquestion) you can see there are approximately 11 questions which might warrant the radeon pro-render tag. Based on that, I don't think it needs a tag yet. Also, were we to create a tag for this, we would probably want it to conform to the render engine tag format: 'NameOfRenderEngine-render-engine' (but that is not a suggestion for you to make that tag as I still don't think it's needed).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can fix the Fabric material setting lower value to the `Reflection Weight` than default 1.0:

[image: RPR Uber for Fabric material]

Result:

[image: Radeon ProRender]

However, the same doesn't fix the Bronze material, so additional answer would be very appreciated.